# MySQL tb_uq Duplicate Row without Fatal Error Output

Tags: php, mysql

```
ALTER TABLE purchase ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (item_id, user_id)

INSERT INTO purchase (item_id, user_id, time) VALUES (:item_id, :user_id, :time)
```

I have a table `item_id`, `user_id`, `time`

`item_id` & `user_id` will be unique(User can only purchase item once)

if user click button and load this SQL again, it will cause `Fatal Error` because row already exist.

My question is I don't want to use extra query to `count(*)` before `INSERT` so is there anyway to just ignore it and avoid `Fatal Error` without extra query?

Comment: The error isn't fatal. You could just do the insert and handle it. That's my approach.

Comment: i got error  Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'tb_uq

Comment: Yes - so you trap that and ignore it, or report the duplicate to the user. Either way, your program can continue.

Comment: I check it at front page, user shouldn't able to press the button, but just in case (hacker may find the path and execute this page without button)

Comment: I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE same id again, but I try to find better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO purchase (item_id, user_id, time) VALUES (:item_id, :user_id, :time)
```